# React and Expressjs to upload a file via REST, but the request is never finished

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express, rest

I have a very simple React page, that all it offers it's a form where you can select a file, and when submitting the form, it get's uploaded to the server doing a POST using axios for it.
Here is the code for my tiny client:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react"
import axios from "axios"


const FileUploadForm = () => {
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState<File | undefined>()
  const formRef = React.useRef(null);

  function handleSubmit(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
    if (!selectedFile) {
      return
    }

    if (!formRef.current) {
      return
    }

    const formData = new FormData(formRef.current)

    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/upload", formData)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("response: %o", response)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
      })
      .finally(() => {
        console.log("done")
      })
  }

  const handleFileInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation()
    const files = e.target.files
    if (!files || files.length === 0) {
      setSelectedFile(undefined)
    } else {
      setSelectedFile(files[0])
    }
  }

  return (
    <form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label>
        Select a file:
        <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" onChange={handleFileInputChange} />
      </label>
      <br />
      <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default FileUploadForm
```

On the server side, I have an equally small server that exposes one endpoint for POSTing the file and uses multer to deal with the parsing of the multipart data. Here is the code for it:

```js
import express, { json } from "express"
import multer from "multer"

const app = express()
const port = 8080

let requestNumber = 0

const upload = multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.originalname)
        },
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, "./uploads")
        },
    })
})

app.use(json())
app.use((request, _response, next) => {
    requestNumber++
    const now = new Date().toLocaleString()
    console.log(` #${requestNumber} [${now}] Serving ${request.method} '${request.path}' from '${request.ip}'`)
    next()
})

app.post("/api/upload", upload.single("file"), (req, res) => {
    console.log("/api/upload started")
    if (!req.file) {
        res.status(422).send(JSON.stringify({ error: "Unable to find file in request" }))
        return
    } else {
        res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({ message: `Got your file: '${req.file.originalname}'` }))
    }
    console.log("/api/upload ended")
})


app.listen(port, () => {
    return console.log(`Express is listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

The tricky part, is that when I hit the upload button, I get a good behavior *most* of the times, but not always. Those times when it's not ok, the request just hangs on the server side. I can see the request being logged with my middleware that just logs requests, but I can never see the line `console.log("/api/upload started")` on my logs when that happens.

Since I'm more comfortable using go, I made yet another tiny server to see if I was doing something wrong with Expressjs, and this is the code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil"
    "os"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/rs/cors"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/api/upload", uploadFile).Methods("POST")

    handler := cors.Default().Handler(r)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handler)

}

func uploadFile(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Default().Println("## Welcome to endpoint!")

    body, err := httputil.DumpRequest(r, false)
    if err != nil {
        handleError(w, fmt.Errorf("unable to dump request: %w", err), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    log.Default().Println("body: ", string(body))

    log.Default().Println("     Hit the endpoint 1")
    // Parse the multipart form
    err = r.ParseMultipartForm(2 << 20) // 10 MB max file size
    if err != nil {
        handleError(w, fmt.Errorf("unable to parse multipart: %w", err), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    log.Default().Println("     Hit the endpoint 2")

    // Get the file from the multipart form
    file, handler, err := r.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        handleError(w, fmt.Errorf("unable to get file from form: %w", err), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()
    log.Default().Println("     Hit the endpoint 3")

    // Create a temporary file on disk to write the uploaded file
    tempFile, err := os.CreateTemp("", "upload")
    if err != nil {
        handleError(w, fmt.Errorf("unable to create temporal folder: %w", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    defer tempFile.Close()

    log.Default().Println("     Hit the endpoint 4")

    // Copy the uploaded file to the temporary file
    _, err = io.Copy(tempFile, file)
    if err != nil {
        handleError(w, fmt.Errorf("unable to copy file to temporal folder: %w", err), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    log.Default().Println("     Hit the endpoint 5")
    // Print some information about the uploaded file
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Uploaded file: %s\n", handler.Filename)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "File size: %d bytes\n", handler.Size)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Temporary file: %s\n", tempFile.Name())
}

func handleError(w http.ResponseWriter, err error, code int) {
    log.Default().Println("error: ", err.Error())
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
}
```

And I have the same inconsistent behavior as in the Expressjs version. My logs lines stop at the line `log.Default().Println("      Hit the endpoint 1")`

I've tried to isolate where the error might be, and I wanted to verify that the frontend was sending all the information that was required for the request to succeed, and I went as far as for running this via wireshark, to get a view at the raw packets on the network. Here is the image for the following scenario:

1. I freshly run my server while I have my client already loaded and with the file selected
2. I hit the upload button on the client, and I see that the server is stucked
3. I hit the upload button on the client again, and I can see the server processing everything correctly, and I can see on the network tab of the browser, that my client got a response.

Here's the picture of the packets that I got using wireshark. Spoiler alert, both requests are identical (Except for the obvious fields like the multipart delimiter and the timestamps)
[image: Wireshark evidence]

So my question is. What am I missing? what's wrong with my approach/code? I've been struggling with this for far more that I'm ok admitting by now and I ran out of ideas.

Here is the `package.json` for my client:

```json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.12",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "axios": "^1.3.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

and here is the package.json for the server:

```json
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npx nodemon index.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.53.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.53.0",
    "eslint": "^8.34.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "tar": "^6.1.13",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  }
}
```

EDIT: Added package.json for both client and server

Comment: Note that you are missing content type on your Axios post call. Check out https://www.bezkoder.com/axios-file-upload/ and see how they set the `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",`

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that and it changes nothing on the request itself (I've checked using wireshark), so I consider it not to be necessary, since the content type is nicely calculated from the FormData and within axios itself.
However, I've tried again with it since you suggested it, and I can say that the behavior is still the same. Sometimes works, sometimes it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

To rule out an internet connectivity issue, I would add this to your app.use logger to test a connection to Google:

```
app.use((request, _response, next) => {
  requestNumber++;
  const now = new Date().toLocaleString();
  console.log(
    ` #${requestNumber} [${now}] Serving ${request.method} '${request.path}' from '${request.ip}'`
  );
  // check if we can connect to google
  require("dns").resolve("www.google.com", function (err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("No connection");
    } else {
      console.log("Connected");
    }
  });
  next();
});
```

If when the issue happens you are unable to connect to Google in the same moment, then it's something related to your connection.

*Original Answer:*

You need to let `Express` know about what type of data is coming in from the client. You're setting `app.use(json())` but not handling for other file types. This would explain the intermittency if you're attempting different files to upload.

A common solution for this is to use [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) with Express.

`const bodyParser = require("body-parser");`

`app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: "text/plain" })); // <--- example config`

You can deal with `Buffers` and `urlencoded` form bodies as well using `body-parser`.

Here's a [working Express Multer sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-express-multer--image-upload-qjzbsc) that demonstrates image upload to the server, then response back to the client.

Comment: Thanks for all that code! It does run perfect with your solution on the web :)

How would this explain the intermittency of the upload? I'm always trying to upload the exact same file. Also, in your example, the body-parser is set to text/plain, while if I'm not mistaken, a form request is a multipart/form content type and multer checks for that by itself.

I've tried adding the body parser, and I'm still having the same error.

One thing to note, is that I'm not running the server as a webserver for my client, so I can actually stop the server, but continue to work with the client.

Comment: One more thing, it's written in the body-parser documentation, that it doesn't support multipart requests

Comment: Can you share your package.json / versions of multer and express?

Comment: Also do you ever see your client-side `catch` or `finally` trigger when that issue occurs? Or that it eventually times-out if you let it?

Comment: Sure! I've added the versions information on the post itself.
And nope, the catch and finally are only called when the timeout hits, otherwise they are just waiting